# JS: добавление элемента в ассоциативный массив в состояния React

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, state, setstate

Использую React, один из элементов состояния `this.state` - ассоциативный массив `this.state.selected`

Подскажите как корректнее изменить этот элемент, добавляя/изменяя в нем запись

Сейчас делаю так:

```
    let tmp = this.state.selected;
    tmp[event.target.id] = event.target.checked;

    this.setState({
        selected: tmp
    });
```

А можно ли это сделать покороче и не создавая явно временный массив, т.е. провести какие-то манипуляции уже непосредственно с `selected` в функции `setState`?

Comment: есть небольшое ощущение что вы уже сразу мутируете this.state.selected, судя по всему это объект который вы не копируете, а делаете ссылку на него и при изменении tmp изменится и this.state.selected. Если я не прав - поправьте меня

Comment: @Илья Паймушкин, честно говоря, без понятия :) но такой подход работает, раз напрямую нельзя записать в read-only `selected`, то выкрутился так, поэтому и задаю вопрос - может как-то можно сделать более правильно, если мой способ кривой (а он все таки по ощущениям кривой, хотя и рабочий)

Answer (score 1):

Делать так не совсем корректно, так как копия массива не создаётся. `tmp` это просто ссылка на массив в стейте и прямая мутация стейта крайне не желательна. Прилагаю рабочий пример как делать это без мутации стейта.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: [
      { id: "1", value: "value1" },
      { id: "2", value: "value2" },
      { id: "3", value: "value3" },
    ],
  };

  clickHandler = ({ target: { value, id } }) => {
    const updatedSelected = this.state.selected.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, value } : item
    );
    this.setState({ selected: updatedSelected });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.selected.map(({ id, value }) => (
          <input key={id} value={value} id={id} onChange={this.clickHandler} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: т.е. предлагаете сделать копию поэлементно?

Comment: @Zhihar в голом реакте это единственный способ.

Comment: На практике именно так и делается, менять элемент массива по индексу массива не совсем серьёзный подход. Динамический список должен состоять из объектов с уникальными ID.

Comment: selected это объект или массив ?

Answer (score 1):

В setState можно передать функцию, которая на вход получает текущий state, развернуть спредом selected и поменять (или добавить) элемент:

```
this.setState(state => ({
  selected: {
    ...state.selected,
    [event.target.id]: event.target.checked
  }
}));
```